# split searchresults into different topics?

Tags: php, search

How could I split the searchresults into topics.

I have e.g. three Topics - cars | computers | culture

all are "custom post types" .

Now a user searches for term "speed" in the searchbox and the resultpage would be something like this:

```
cars --- 

2 Posts with "speed" in Cars.
searchresults

computers ---

10 posts with "speed" in Computers
searchresults

culture ---

0 nothing found for "speed" in Cutlure.
searchresults
```

any way to make this work? Need different loops I guess?

thank yoU!

AD

Answer (score 0):

If your topics are categories, you can use the [Search by Category](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-by-category/) plugin.

Comment: Hi fdsa - thanks for the reply. My topics are "Custom Post Types"....I thought about something like different loops or something...

Comment: You can put your custom post types into categories.

Comment: If they don't already have categories, you can use [register_taxonomy_for_object_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) so they are able to use categories.

Comment: thanks for the reply - I checked the plugin page, but I'd like to have a normal search - only the results on the search results page should be grouped. No need to select from a category before the search. thx